# 403 Error on ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I try to do my first project on Zend Framework 1.11 and i'm using XAMPP as my localhost,when i try to run my "index.php" file on localhost/ZF/public/index.php,i get a same error as below:
Access forbidden!

```
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
08/24/12 19:13:35
Apache/2.2.9 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.6
```

what's wrong and how can i fix that ? i'm set .htaccess file same as zend framework user guide reference but error is exist!

Comment: how is your apache config set up? Do you have mod_rewrite enabled? Did you check the apache access log to see any more info? It's windows so filesystem permissions should not be a problem.

Comment: you SHOULD check owners and permissions just to be sure! Let me know if this helps you. http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=143679

Comment: yep,my OS is windows and i did set AllowOverride All, too!

Comment: i'm set full control permission to my ZF folder and i now get ,500 ERROR !

Comment: are you sure you're running XAMPP? You should be reporting Apache version 2.4.2 php ver 5.4.4 openssl 1.0.1c. Your installation is not reporting anything like that.

Comment: yeah i'm using xampp,I learn to solve my problems by uncomment this line of code in httpd.conf:LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and enable mod_rewrite ;)